# ELF Parsing : Accessing a DIE Directly using pyelftools

Tags: python, binary, elf, dwarf, pyelftools

I need a method for accessing DIE's directly using their offset.  So far, I have found that there is a method for the Computation Unit (CU) object in which you can access a DIE from its offset.

I.e. :

```
cu._get_DIE(die.attributes['DW_AT_type'].value)
```

However if you try to access a DIE that is outside of the current CU, you are out of bounds because that DIE isn't indexed under that CU.

The best way I can think of to accomplish this is to loop through the CU's and create a comprehensive list of DIE's using the offset as an index.

It seems like there should be a method for the `DWARFInfo` class that you can access any DIE as long as you have it's offset.

The reason that I need to do this is because I am looping through all of the CU's to generate a list of my globals, and I need to reference DIE's in different CU's to retrieve the type information as I go.

Answer (score 0):

pyelftools seems to express references as value relative to the compilation unit so you'll probably need to include the CU information in your list of globals.

Check out https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools/issues/27.  It indicates that the references can be relative to the compilation unit.  In fact, the DWARF specification says that, too: http://dwarfstd.org/doc/dwarf-2.0.0.pdf#page=71